# Project management tool that can produce different charts

Tags: project-management

I'm doing my school assignment for software engineering, and given we have some user stories that we have broken down to tasks and estimated them, we would like to produce the following charts:

- Gant Chart
- [PERT chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_evaluation_and_review_technique)
- Kanban Diagram

We are following scrum methodology.

I'm looking for software that does all this together, and it's free or comes with a trial. If there's no software that does it, then please recommend anything that can do more than one of the charts specified.

It doesn't matter if it's web based or desktop.

I have checked Microsoft project and it seems like it doesn't make PERT charts anymore.